# Credential not load in Claudiajs hello word example for aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, claudiajs

I try to use `aws` with [ClaudiaJS](https://claudiajs.com) so first I downlolad [hello world example](https://github.com/claudiajs/example-projects/tree/master/hello-world) from claudiajs github and then on my aws create a user with these `AWSLambdaFullAccess`,`IAMFullAccess` and `AmazonAPIGatewayAdministrator` and then configure `.aws/credentials` file with `awscli` and change profile name from default to claudia and now my credentials is something like this :

```
[claudia]
aws_access_key_id = xxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxx
```

after that according to the tutorial I run `npm i` and then `npm start`.the scripts is like this  :

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "claudia create --name hello-world --region us-east-1 --handler main.handler",
    "test": "claudia test-lambda",
    "deploy": "claudia update"
},
```

but after `npm start` I get these errors :

```
npm start

> hello-world@1.0.0 start /home/interact/Try/hello-world
> claudia create --name hello-world --region us-east-1 --handler 
main.handler

initialising IAM role   iam.createRole  RoleName=hello-world-executor
{ Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 169.254.169.254:80
at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1186:14)
 message: 'Missing credentials in config',
 code: 'CredentialsError',
 errno: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
 syscall: 'connect',
 address: '169.254.169.254',
 port: 80,
 time: 2018-06-13T07:50:47.292Z,
 originalError: 
   { message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers',
 code: 'CredentialsError',
 errno: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
 syscall: 'connect',
 address: '169.254.169.254',
 port: 80,
 time: 2018-06-13T07:50:47.292Z,
 originalError: 
  { code: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
    errno: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '169.254.169.254',
    port: 80,
    message: 'connect EHOSTUNREACH 169.254.169.254:80' } } }
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! errno 1
 npm ERR! hello-world@1.0.0 start: `claudia create --name hello-world --region us-east-1 --handler main.handler`
 npm ERR! Exit status 1
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! Failed at the hello-world@1.0.0 start script.
 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
 additional logging output above.

 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 npm ERR!     /home/interact/.npm/_logs/2018-06-13T07_50_47_317Z-
 debug.log
```

and the message is :

```
  enter code here`message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers'
```

I search on SF and on net but nothing found that can solve my problem.

my node version is `v8.11.3` and npm version is `5.6.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily solve your issue using two way

1.By changing  .aws/credentials file. Rename [claudia] to [default]

```
 [default]
    aws_access_key_id = xxxxxxxxx
    aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxxxxx
```

2.Set the AWS_PROFILE environment variable.

```
AWS_PROFILE=deployment claudia <options>
```

if you want multiple AWS cli users you can add using this way.

Modify .aws/credentials file

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = xxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxxxxx

[claudia]
aws_access_key_id = xxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add AWS_PROFILE=*profile_name* to your package.json file.  This will set the profile just for that command.  This is useful if you have multiple projects with different accounts.

For example:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "AWS_PROFILE=claudia claudia create --name hello-world --region us-east-1 --handler main.handler",
    "test": "AWS_PROFILE=claudia claudia test-lambda",
    "deploy": "AWS_PROFILE=claudia claudia update"
},
```